# Skip defining return type in Callable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a following situation, I am passing a function to a class constructor, the function needs to have 0 arguments, and can return various complex objects types which would require a lot of type hinting to specify them correctly.

I would like to type hint the need for exactly 0 arguments in this function, but also I do not want to specify all the possible objects type variants that this function could return.

I was thinking that the closest to what I need is `Callable[[], Any]` but that seems to indicate that this function can return truly Anything, while in fact it should return only some fixed amount of return types.

Is there anyway to `pass` defining return type in callable, and only type hint arguments needed?
Ideally I would do something like this, but as expected, unfortunately, this shows an error: `Callable[[]]`

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from type hinting exactly? AFAIK, `Any` is the closest to pass (if you DONT type hint something, it should be implicitly set to `Any` by linters / type checkers anyway, so `Any` *is* the same as not type hinting)

Comment: @Xtrem532 to precise - I think it was quite a couple objects types' variations that could be returned, and I didn't want to have to specify them all at that time taking into consideration fact that it was likely to change soon (I think I was in refactoring process).

However I can think of another reason now, which would be to not repeat big type hints for custom functions over and over again (or is there a better way to not repeat type hints?)

Comment: You can just assign Type hints to variables and the reuse them. So just do `my_type = List[Tuple[int, Tuple[str, ...]]]` an then you can do `def my_func() -> my_type`

Comment: thanks. that's helpful. (just a side note - shouldn't it be rather by convention, written as `MyType` since we are defining a type here which would be the same as defining object type by defining it's class - thus the PascalCase. correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I have no idea how to write PEP8 compliant  code. Pylint does that for me.